How do I pass a value from a middleware to controllers?
I've been scratching my head as to how I could pass a value from a middleware to the subsequent controllers.
My exact requirement is to carry out token-based authentication in the middleware and pass the retrieved user data to all the subsequent controllers.
In node.js-express, I would assign the details to req.user or add an attribute to res.locals. Neither works here for obvious reasons. What's the way to go here?, other than calling a function in every single controller.

why req.user doesn't works ?

Help us help you - share an example of what you tried, and indicate what exactly is the problem with it.
